# vs code not transpiling ts files

Tags: typescript, compilation, visual-studio-code, transpiler

I have Visual Studio Code (version 1.7.2) installed and typescript 1.8. I have built a simple react-native project in a folder. (The react app works just fine as I can run it in a debugger). Now I try to integrate typescript. But vs code does not transpile my code neither on save (ctrl+s) nor on build (ctrl+b). Here is my `tsconfig.json` file (located in the root of my project):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",    
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true          
  },  
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And here is the `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\TypeScript\\1.8\\tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Compilation occurs just fine as vs code is able to pick syntax errors from a test file calle "mytest.ts"
But on save or on build there is not "mytest.js" file generated. I have followed the instructions from this https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript

still I'm not able to get vs code transpile my code.

Any help, hint toward the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve my problem by modifying the `tasks.json` file like this:

```
    {
    ...

    "args": ["-p", "${workspaceRoot}"],

    ...

}
```